# Mobilefirst 7 -> windows 8 URL activation scheme parameters

Tags: cordova, windows-8, winjs, ibm-mobilefirst

I've a problem with activation protocols in mobilefirst / windows8(.1).
In a standard winJS app I can get the parameters after activating an app by custom protocol in the canonical way:

```
   //register event
    WinJS.Application.addEventListener("activated", onActivatedHandler, false);

//handle
function onActivatedHandler(eventArgs) {
   if (eventArgs.detail.kind == Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.protocol) 
   {    
       // The received URI is eventArgs.detail.uri.rawUri
   }
}
```

My problem is that in the app written in mobilefirst the app don't raise event! 
Someone has similar problems?
Thanks, 
f.

Comment: is this in a IBM MobileFirst (Worklight)  app?

Comment: Yes, is in a mobilefirst app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you calling the `addEventListener` ? Perhaps, the `onactivated` event has already been raised before you called the `addEventListener`.

I was able to intercept the loading in the `cordova.js` file and added an event listener and the appropriate function was fired.